# Escape "GMT" for Google Charts Timestamp

Tags: javascript, json, time, google-visualization

I have Google Charts set up with the hAxis as a timeline. My client wants to display the time in 24 hour time, with the GMT offset printed along side, and the date. My code is pretty simple, but the "GMT" label is generating an interesting side effect.

Here's my format code: `"format": 'H:MM '+' GMT'+$scope.offset.toString()+'\r\n MM/dd/yyyy'` but the result is:

```
6:03 AD3T+7
03/21/2016
```

AD3T from "GMT", which is probably the result of passing G (to get AD?) and M to get the month (3), and the T apparently has no effect.

My question is, in the Google Charts JSON object, how can I format the time stamp to have a human-readable label of "GMT" and the offset? Do I need to escape "GMT"? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple different ways to apply formatting, easiest being `hAxis.format`
it follows the [ICU pattern set](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classSimpleDateFormat.html#_details)
See table under **Detailed Description** for all the patterns available.

I think this may get you close, including the offset.
`'H:MM ZZZZ \r\n MM/dd/yyyy'`

You can also provide your own tick marks.
Which means you can apply your own custom format generated in JavaScript.
The following example assumes this formatting has already occurred.

Provide the typical object google accepts for a column value in an array
one for each tick mark you need displayed
`{v: new Date(2013, 4,  5, 3, 6, 0, 0), f: '3:05 GMT-04:00 \r\n 05/05/2013'}`

Following are two examples, one using `hAxis.format`, the other `ticks` ...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = [
    ['Date', 'Value'],                          //provide custom formatting
    [ {v: new Date(2013, 4,  4, 1, 3, 0, 0), f: '1:05 GMT-04:00 \r\n 05/04/2013'}, 38177],
    [ {v: new Date(2013, 4,  5, 3, 6, 0, 0), f: '3:05 GMT-04:00 \r\n 05/05/2013'}, 38705],
    [ {v: new Date(2013, 4, 12, 2, 4, 0, 0), f: '2:05 GMT-04:00 \r\n 05/12/2013'}, 38210],
    [ {v: new Date(2013, 4, 13, 4, 8, 0, 0), f: '4:05 GMT-04:00 \r\n 05/13/2013'}, 38029],
    [ {v: new Date(2013, 4, 19, 8, 9, 0, 0), f: '8:05 GMT-04:00 \r\n 05/19/2013'}, 38823],
    [ {v: new Date(2013, 4, 23, 2, 4, 0, 0), f: '2:05 GMT-04:00 \r\n 05/23/2013'}, 38345],
    [ {v: new Date(2013, 4, 24, 1, 1, 0, 0), f: '1:05 GMT-04:00 \r\n 05/24/2013'}, 38436],
    [ {v: new Date(2013, 4, 30, 6, 8, 0, 0), f: '6:05 GMT-04:00 \r\n 05/30/2013'}, 38447]
  ];

  var tickMarks = [];
  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    tickMarks.push(data[i][0]);
    i = i + 1;
  }
  tickMarks.push(data[data.length - 1][0]);

  var optionsA = {
    hAxis: {
      format: 'H:MM ZZZZ \r\n MM/dd/yyyy',
    },
    legend: 'none',
    pointSize: 5
  };

  var optionsB = {
    hAxis: {
      ticks: tickMarks
    },
    legend: 'none',
    pointSize: 5
  };

  var chartA = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_divA'));
  chartA.draw(google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data), optionsA);

  var chartB = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_divB'));
  chartB.draw(google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data), optionsB);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_divA"></div>
<div id="chart_divB"></div>
```